# JQuery $.each returns only the first item of JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "mesta": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.094046,15.893415],
            "nazev": "Město Jaroměřice nad Rokytnou"
        },
        {
            "latlng": [49.44119,18.09461],
            "nazev": "Obec Vidče"
        },
        {
            "latlng": [49.5047,17.10139],
            "nazev": "Obec Smržice"
        }
    ],
    "orp": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.2156,15.87819],
            "nazev": "Město Třebíč (ORP)"
        },
        {
            "latlng": [49.457623,18.142622],
            "nazev": "Město Rožnov pod Radhoštěm (ORP)"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to iterate over the object, I only get the first item (mesta) on alert. According to jsonlint the syntax is correct. Am I missing something?

```
function loadMarkers() {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

        $.each(data,function(index,obj) {
                alert(index);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/usakic

Comment: Assuming that *is* the JSON response, [this should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/TzqMA/). Are you **sure** that's *exactly* what's being returned by the server?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bFFyL/. doublecheck the returned object.

Comment: Guys what if you try over here? http://www.zimmi.cz/edpp/. Does it work for you as well?

Comment: @zimmi - If I run `$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { console.log(data); });` in the Chrome console on that page, the response contains only one property, `mesta`.

Comment: Now I see. Ehm, what can I do about it? Can it be server-side problem?

Comment: @zimmi: http://www.zimmi.cz/edpp/data.json: How is it getting generated? It only contains `mesta`.

Comment: your data.json contains only mesta http://www.zimmi.cz/edpp/data.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the response from the server, not your JavaScript. I ran the following code in the console on your page:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
});
```

The result looked like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is only one property (`mesta`, an array with three elements) in the returned object.

You can confirm this by [visiting the `data.json` file directly](http://www.zimmi.cz/edpp/data.json).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the response you got. [$.each works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/8JSh5/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your JSON object or $.each function i was able to iterate over both keys in the above data here http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/N2C3j/

the issue seems to be with your getJSON call i doubt that your call returns only the first element did you debug the code and see what is the fetched json data for the call

Comment: I ran ur site and I got two keys in response and your iterator is also printing both in ur console seems fine to me check with firebug

Comment: I guess then ur issue is with chrome browser your code works fine in firefox and returns two keys mesta and orp

Answer (score 0):

You are Selecting Each object which has an array of objects.

Solution probably would be that you put each in each or don't use jQuery.each
but a simple for like ... (asuming the returned object is called data)

```
for(obj in data){
    for(entry in data[obj]){
    {
       console.log(entry)
       ....
    }
}
```